# Lion - customize toolbar

Tags: macos, applications, customization, bug

In Snow Leopard you could right click an application toolbar icon and select "Remove item", this is no longer possible in Lion. If I select "Customize toolbar" I get the customization panel, but it's not possible to do any changes.

Anyone know if this is a bug or intentional?

Any way around it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<kbd>⌘CMD</kbd>-drag to get the item out of the toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried, when in Customize Toolbar, to drag the items out of the actual toolbar? It works for me in Safari.

Comment: same here.. (10.7.2)